# Kotlin. How to reset each array element to zero?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, kotlin-extension, val

I'm using FloatArray:

```
  private val values = FloatArray(5)
```

At some point, I need to reset each array value to zero. I tried doing it like this:

```
  values.onEachIndexed { index, value -> value[index] = 0.0f  }
```

But I am getting this error

> No set method providing array access

At the same time, this code works (outside onEachIndexed) and I can set the value for the element:

```
values[1] = 4.0f
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because `value` there represents an element of the array, not the array itself, so you cannot use `[]` to set it. Reassigning it a new value will not work either, because `value` is a lambda parameter.

There is a builtin method for filling the entirety (or a portion) the array - [`fill`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fill.html)

```
values.fill(0.0f)
```